# Do I need to do any extra work to secure my sqlite database in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am using core data to store data in the sqlite database. Do I need to take any extra measures to secure them?.

And also, I found some sqlite browser apps in the appstore. My doubt is, do these apps able to access sqlite db used in my app or how does these apps work/useful to the developer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For security you can use encrypted db that has key, when you open your app,use your key to decrypt your db. because your db is encrypted, no one else can use your db.

Comment: have a look, http://sokol8.blogspot.in/2011/05/iphone-sqlite-data-encryption-sqlcipher.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends to which degree you want to protect your db. If you don't consider jailbreaked devices, it is enough to store your db in the private folder of your application that nobody else can access.

A user of a jailbreaked device however can read the whole file system including you sqlite db. If you have to consider also this risk, you can encrypt the database as @Invincible suggests. The problem here is that you still need to store your password somewhere in your application that with some effort can be reverse engineered and extracted. You can and should use some obfuscation methods to store your password but also this does not give you 100% security.

The problem of security on an "open" (jailbreaked) platform is that you do not have an access to any information to what your attacker would not have access. However you can make the situation of the attacker significantly more difficult by applying different obfuscation and encryption techniques. How much effort you should invest? You should consider the following factors:

- risk of loosing your sensitive data <=> the gain of the attacker
- your effort you are ready to invest <=> how much effort the attacker would invest